# The fully qualified name of the bean's class, except if it serves only as a parent definition for child bean definitions

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I want to integrate Apache Tiles in my Spring Project I have followed steps on [spring-tiles integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles) but I get error at: 
[image]
**providing only related code**

project structure is
[image]

servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- Tiles Configuration -->

<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
           <!--  <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</beans:value> -->
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass">
        <beans:value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="order" value="0"/>
</beans:bean>
```

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/layout/classic.jsp">       
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Blog of Blogs"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp"/>
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>blog</groupId>
<artifactId>app-example</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>blog</name>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <apache.tiles>3.0.3</apache.tiles>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have tried a lot but could not found any solution to this error, can any one see what is wrong with this?

Comment: Please post all the required configuration code here so we can debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK there is one big mistake in your pom.xml, change :

```
<org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
```

to

```
<org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
```

I have noticed this important thing here [Configuring Apache Tiles 3 and Spring 4 MVC](http://frameworkonly.com/configuring-apache-tiles-3-and-spring-4-mvc/) you can download sample project and get in touch with it.
Hope It would work for you!

Comment: finally it is resolved, Thanks for referring a source on the net.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Apache-Tiles version ***3.0.3*** but the `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer` is available from Spring ***3.2***.

See the Spring documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles3/TilesConfigurer.html).

To get around this issue you could either use:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer
```

or upgrade your Spring version to 3.2 or above.

Comment: what did, changing to tiles2.TilesConfigurer ?

Comment: I'm getting`Multiple annotations found at this line: - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean] Offending resource: file [app/src/main/webapp/ WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean] - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.`

Comment: thanks for your time, but answer above resolved this problem and my app is working! thanks to @ArshadAli

Comment: yeah the second suggestion I made to upgrade to a newer version of spring is what @ArshadAli has also suggested. glad it's been resolved